Rails + PostgreSQL: Find records between given time intervals
I created columns range_start and range_stop, the "Rails" type is t.time (in PostgreSQL, it's time without time zone). I intended to store here time values, such as 16:30.
Example (and format) of data stored in these columns:

NULL
15:45:00
23:00:00
00:00:00

Some prerequisites:
In application.rb, I have the following:
config.time_zone = 'Europe/Berlin' # For presentation/user-facing times
config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc  # For database interactions

In PostgreSQL, data is saved in the UTC format. When I run SHOW timezone;, I get this result: Europe/Berlin.
When I want to save some time-information to the database, I do it like this:
model_instance.update(range_start: Time.zone.parse('19:00').utc)

Here, my expectation is that the 19:00 (time in Berlin) will be saved to the database in the UTC format, which will convert to 17:00:00 => and this works, this value is saved in the database.
Now, I would like to display this 17:00:00 UTC from database in the view of my Rails app, so I tried the following:
<%= model.range_start.strftime("%H:%M") # prints '18:00' %>
<%= model.range_start.in_time_zone("Europe/Berlin").strftime("%H:%M") # prints '18:00' %>
<%= model.range_start.in_time_zone(TZInfo::Timezone.get('Europe/Berlin').name).strftime("%H:%M") # prints '18:00' %>

This confuses me - I saved to the database 19:00 in Berlin's time, but I am not able to retrieve it back from the database.
Berlin is UTC/GMT +2 hours, so I would expect that +2 would be added to the UTC stored in the datbaase. But Rails for some reason adds only +1 hour. I also tried to incorporate TzInfo that is supposed to deal with DST, but I was still not able to properly convert the time back to 19:00.
What am I missing here?

EDIT: I also tried to change the column range_start from time without time zone to time with time zone, but with the same result.

Timezones are hard. My guess would be DST.  If you read through https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES there's a decent explanation why times with timezone have problems if they are without date. I hate to be this guy who instead of giving the answer asks you why are you doing it this way. But is there a solution for your problem where you could use Datetime types with timezone? (BTW. your title is confusing, the question seems to have little to do with finding, more with conversions between TZs)

I just spotted your edit. And I'm more convinced the DST is the issue. What do you see when you call ActiveRecord::Type::Time.new.cast(Time.zone.parse("19:00").utc) in your console?

@Greg It is an DST issue. About an hour ago I gave up and changed the data type to timetz. It seems to be working properly now. I also tried to incorporate some gems that are designed to deal with the DSL issues (tzinfo), but it didn't really help me to resolve it.

What do get you when you .strftime("%H:%M") on a Time.zone.parse('19:00').utc directly, without the value going through the db? What's Time.now.strftime("%:z")? What's your config.active_record.time_zone_aware_attributes and ActiveRecord::Base.time_zone_aware_types? @max That's not true. PostgreSQL datetimes do work like that, plain times don't, which is why timetz needs 4 more bytes than time - to store the timezone.

@max Here's the doc: "The appropriate time zone offset is recorded in the time with time zone value and is output as stored; it is not adjusted to the active time zone."

@Zegarek wrong. "For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in UTC (Universal Coordinated Time, traditionally known as Greenwich Mean Time, GMT)".

@max You're confusing timestamp and timestamptz with time and timetz.

@max I did. Look, you can even try it yourself: https://dbfiddle.uk/3-sLWxHD Again, you keep repeating remarks and quotes that concern timestamptz and timestamp, not time and timetz. These are four separate data types.
